# Opening Google map app for navigation from another Application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, url-scheme

I have tried to open google map application from my app using these code

```
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
            "comgooglemaps://?saddr=\(fromLatitude),\(fromLongitude)&daddr=\(toLatitude),\(toLongitude)&directionsmode=driving")!)
    }else{
        showAlert()
    }
```

I have installed google map in my iphone but this code always going to else part

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Launch Services (part of the Core Services framework in macOS)
>   provides support for launching apps and matching document types to
>   apps.

You should include this in your `info.plist` file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

You can open in browser if google maps is not installed.

```
// if GoogleMap installed
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
        "comgooglemaps://?saddr=\(fromLatitude),\(fromLongitude)&daddr=\(toLatitude),\(toLongitude)&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)

} else {
    // if GoogleMap App is not installed
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
                "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=\(fromLatitude),\(fromLongitude)&daddr=\(toLatitude),\(toLongitude)&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)
}
```

Comment: You saved me . One more doubt is there any other method for opening in built navigation instead of google map

Comment: if the user is not installed google map application what will i do?

Comment: This opens Google Maps and displays the directions to the destination, but is there a way to actually start the navigation mode without the user having to click on the button to start it? It works like that on Android but not on iOS for some reason.

Comment: @rajesh kumar
Google map application is opening but why not loading first time.

Answer (score 1):

In your info.plist file add the following:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

And to open Google Maps app from your app you can use the following method. This method will be used in case you like to navigate

```
    + (void)routeWithGoogleMaps:(CLLocation *)destination{
        NSString *stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=driving", destination.coordinate.latitude, destination.coordinate.longitude];
        NSString* browserStringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=driving", destination.coordinate.latitude, destination.coordinate.longitude];

        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
        NSURL* browserUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:browserStringUrl];
        bool isGoogleMapsAppInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]];

        if(isGoogleMapsAppInstalled && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        else
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:browserUrl];
    }
```

If you don't want to navigate but you just want to open Google Maps app just at the location the modify the url from this

```
@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=driving"
```

to this

```
@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%f,%f"
```

For Swift users you can use the following:

```
// if GoogleMap installed
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
        "comgooglemaps://?saddr=\(fromLatitude),\(fromLongitude)&daddr=\(toLatitude),\(toLongitude)&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)

} else {
    // if GoogleMap App is not installed
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
                "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=\(fromLatitude),\(fromLongitude)&daddr=\(toLatitude),\(toLongitude)&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)
}
```

Comment: Google map application is opening but why not loading first time

Answer (score 0):

> If your app is linked on or after iOS 9.0, you must declare the URL schemes you want to pass to this method. Do this by using the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array in your Xcode project’s Info.plist file. For each URL scheme you want your app to use with this method, add it as a string in this array.

For  comgooglemaps://

simply add this string without ://.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: How to open inbuilt map for navigation instead of google map?

Comment: @MidhunNarayan Does that help ?

Comment: no need this mapkit is not providing sufficient data so i will go with google map itself

Comment: Use like     `MKMapItem.openMaps(with: [currentLocationMapItem, mapItem], launchOptions: launchOptions)`